# Cordova iOS and Android webview stream pdf download

Tags: php, android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a Cordova project where inAppBrowser plugin is used to load a php webapp. In that app there are dynamically generated links to forced download pdf (download.php?id=xxxxx) using following php code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

My Cordova app doesn't do anything with those download.php?id=xxxxx links.

This is my index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>MyApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
            var url = 'http://sub.domain.com/app/en/login/' // change to whatever you want
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no');
        }, false)
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I make downloads work in this Cordova app? If download is not possible, is it possible to let the user 'view' the pdf?

Comment: Yeah, webviews don't download files. On iOS you can just view it. On Android you can use _system option so it should launch an intent so other app opens it.

Comment: @jcesarmobile That doesn't seem to work. Tried both target="_system" and <a href="#" onclick="window.open('download/?id=xxxxxxx', '_system');">Download Invoice</a>, but to no avail. Any other options?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear what I meant. Instead of serving forced downloads you have to serve the actual file. And by using _system I meant for inAppBroser (`cordova.InAppBrowser.open(fileUrl, '_system');`), but didn't realize you were already displaying your website on inAppBrowser, so that's not going to work for Android. You can maybe use the loadstart event and check if the url has download.php on it and then open a new inAppBrowser window

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks for the info. Can you give an answer where you also illustrate your solution in code? Thanks!

Comment: @andyderuyter if you are looking for answer related to download pdf capability in cordova app and display the pdf for viewing, then i guess you gotta use file and file opener plugin. Suggest you to refer to this github repo - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations where  you have the working sample app that download pdf from server and displays in the app. Please go through the readme. It should help you out

Comment: @andyderuyter did you had a look at the sample app?

Comment: I did... but I'm not a mobile developer, so didn't know how to implement. For the time being I 'fixed' it by displaying the pdf in an iframe where it shows embedded Google Docs Viewer.